# On tap some row in List with a button the action is triggered even clicking outside the button area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm creating a home screen with a list of custom components. These componentes are one or more click areas with navigation link or buttons, like the above image:

[App Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzWjd.png)

But the click area is not respected, if I click in any space in the row the click is triggered even it's outside the button/navigation link area

[Click buttom area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiCNh.png)

[Click bug video](https://youtu.be/vOlo0cib2lo)

The code is available in https://github.com/isaquedev/swiftui-list-click-bug and bellow:

Home

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var items: [HomeSection] = [
        HomeSection(title: "Mais próximos", type: .nearest),
        HomeSection(title: "", type: .list, items: [
            SectionItem(title: "Românticos", cover: "prato-1"),
            SectionItem(title: "Especiais", cover: "prato-2"),
            SectionItem(title: "Agradáveis", cover: "prato-1"),
            SectionItem(title: "Interessantes", cover: "prato-2"),
        ])
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VList {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                switch item.type {
                case .nearest:
                    NearestCell(title: item.title)
                case .list:
                    ListCell(items: item.items ?? [])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VList

```
import SwiftUI

struct VList<Content:View>: View {
    
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    content()
                }
            }
        } else {
            List {
                content()
                .padding(.horizontal, -20)
            }
            .onAppear {
                UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
                UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NearestCell

```
import SwiftUI

struct NearestCell: View {
    
    var title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.title)
                .padding(.bottom, 16)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Veja restaurantes a sua volta")
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("Click")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Visualizar")
                })
                .padding(.top, 16)
            }
            .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .padding(.vertical, 16)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
            )
        }
        .padding(.all, 16)
        .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

ListCell

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListCell: View {
    
    var items: [SectionItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Categorias")
                .font(.title)
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        VStack {
                            Image(item.cover)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                                .clipped()

                            Text(item.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 113)
        }
        .padding(.all, 16)
    }
}
```

Home Section

```
enum HomeSectionType {
    
    case nearest, list
    
}

class HomeSection: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var type: HomeSectionType
    var items: [SectionItem]?
    
    init(title: String, type: HomeSectionType, items: [SectionItem]? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        self.type = type
        self.items = items
    }
    
}
```

SectionItem

```
class SectionItem: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var cover: String

    init(title: String, cover: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.cover = cover
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your code, it is all because of `List`, `List` apply action of a `Button` of a row to all row, for solving the issue use just `Text` and put action code inside `onTapGesture`.

```
    struct NearestCell: View {
    
    var title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.title)
                .padding(.bottom, 16)
            
            VStack {
                
                
                Text("Veja restaurantes a sua volta")
                
                Text("Visualizar")                      // <<: here
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .padding(.top, 16)
                    .onTapGesture { print("Click") }    // <<: here
                
                
            }
            .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .padding(.vertical, 16)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
            )
        }
        .padding(.all, 16)
        .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have any workaround to work with NavigationLink for this problem? Buttons I can replace for Text, but NavigationLink is important to work as expected

Comment: But in your code was Button not NavigationLink, is it a new question you are asking?

Comment: I use in this example a button, but the same problem occur using navigation link. I click in some place of the row and the navigation link is triggered.

Comment: I think for that we should implement another way, I can help with that also, but please accept this answer because answers the question, and we try solve that issue in another question together. stackOverFlow does not allow us multi questions in one post. thank you.

Comment: Did you follow up with another question regarding the NavigationLink case? I'm facing the same problem and would love to see it :)